# How to handle authentication pop-up using Selenium 4 Chrome Driver Java/Kotlin

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 4 for Chrome and the language is Java/Kotlin.

The authentication pop is neither an alert nor a frame.
(getting an exception when I try driver.switchTo().alert() and driver.switchTo().frame(n)

I would like to do this without sending the credentials in the url.

Please let me know how to sign in by entering the credentials.